# Zend 1.12 internal links to controllers don't work anymore

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I need a little help to understand what's wrong.

I've got this problem since yesterday.Links to internal pages don't work anymore as i was reencoding my phtml files to utf-8 (without BOM).

Her's my index.php (root)

```
    <?php   
    ob_start(); 
    define('PATH', "./");
    define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . 'application/'));   
    define('SITE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application/')); 
    define('APP_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/application/'); 

    set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . 'library' . PATH_SEPARATOR .  get_include_path());
    set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . 'application' . PATH_SEPARATOR .  get_include_path());
    set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . 'application/controllers' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
    set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . 'application/models/' .  PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
    set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . '' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());


    $errMsg = array();
    $succMsg = array();


    require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
    $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
    Zend_Session::start();
    $mySession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('default');


   try {
     require 'application/Bootstrap.php';
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
      echo '<html><body><center>'
       . 'An exception occured while bootstrapping the application.';
    if (defined('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT') && APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT != 'production') {
        echo '<br /><br />' . $exception->getMessage() . '<br />'
           . '<div align="left">Stack Trace:' 
           . '<pre>' . $exception->getTraceAsString() . '</pre></div>';
    }
    echo '</center></body></html>';
    exit(1);
}   

   // DISPATCH:  Dispatch the request using the front controller.
   // The front controller is a singleton, and should be setup by now. We 
   // will grab an instance and dispatch it, which dispatches your 
   // application.
   /* $fcontroller=Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance() ;
   $router = $fcontroller->getRouter();$appRoutes=array();
   $appRoutes['varun']= new    Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/varun',array('module'=> 'default','controller' => 'index','action' => 'support'));                
   foreach($appRoutes as $key=>$cRouter){
     $router->addRoute( $key,  $cRouter );
   }
 */ 

 $mySession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('default');
 Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->dispatch();
 ob_flush();
```

Here's my .htaccess

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5 .php .phtml
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Here's my application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

database.adapter       = "PDO_MYSQL"
database.params.dbname = "dbname"
database.params.host = "host.com"
database.params.username = "username"
database.params.password = "password"
database.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
database.params.charset  = UTF8

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// APPLICATION CONSTANTS - Set the constants to use in this application.
// These constants are accessible throughout the application, even in ini 
// files. We optionally set APPLICATION_PATH here in case our entry point 
// isn't index.php (e.g., if required from our test suite or a script).

defined('APPLICATION_PATH') or define('APPLICATION_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'utils/TeeImageUtils.php');
include_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'application/configs/config.inc.php');

//include_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'includes/config.php');
//include_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'paypal_pro.inc.php');

include_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'application/configs/general.php');

//include_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'application/configs/messages.php');
//include_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'facebook.php');

defined('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT') or define('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT','development');
ini_set('display_errors','on');

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//error_reporting(0);
// FRONT CONTROLLER - Get the front controller.
// The Zend_Front_Controller class implements the Singleton pattern, which is a
// design pattern used to ensure there is only one instance of
// Zend_Front_Controller created on each request.

$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

//Zend_Controller_Front::run('../application/controllers');
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($frontController); die;
// CONTROLLER DIRECTORY SETUP - Point the front controller to your action
// controller directory.

$frontController->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH .'application/controllers');

// APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT - Set the current environment
// Set a variable in the front controller indicating the current environment --
// commonly one of development, staging, testing, production, but wholly
// dependent on your organization and site's needs.

$frontController->setParam('env', APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT);

// LAYOUT SETUP - Setup the layout component
// The Zend_Layout component implements a composite (or two-step-view) pattern
// In this call we are telling the component where to find the layouts scripts.

Zend_Layout::startMvc(APPLICATION_PATH . 'application/layouts/scripts', false,"layout");

// VIEW SETUP - Initialize properties of the view object
// The Zend_View component is used for rendering views. Here, we grab a "global"
// view instance from the layout object, and specify the doctype we wish to
// use -- in this case, XHTML1 Strict.
//$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
//$view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
//$view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
// Add helpers prefixed with Helper in helpers/

Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath('application/helpers/','Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_');

//$value = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Myhelper')->displaythis();
//$value = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Myhelper')->liscenceInfo();

// CONFIGURATION - Setup the configuration object
// The Zend_Config_Ini component will parse the ini file, and resolve all of
// the values for the given section.  Here we will be using the section name
// that corresponds to the APP's Environment

$configuration = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH .'application/configs/application.ini','development');

// DATABASE ADAPTER - Setup the database adapter
// Zend_Db implements a factory interface that allows developers to pass in an
// adapter name and some parameters that will create an appropriate database
// adapter object.  In this instance, we will be using the values found in the
// "database" section of the configuration obj.

$dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory($configuration->database);

// DATABASE TABLE SETUP - Setup the Database Table Adapter
// Since our application will be utilizing the Zend_Db_Table component, we need 
// to give it a default adapter that all table objects will be able to utilize 
// when sending queries to the db.

$dbAdapter->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($dbAdapter);

// REGISTRY - setup the application registry
// An application registry allows the application to store application 
// necessary objects into a safe and consistent (non global) place for future 
// retrieval.  This allows the application to ensure that regardless of what 
// happends in the global scope, the registry will contain the objects it 
// needs.

$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->configuration = $configuration;
$registry->dbAdapter     = $dbAdapter;

//$helper = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_MWWMaster;
//$helper->preDispatch();
//Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper('MWWMaster');
//$hb = new Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker;
//$hb->getHelper('MWWMaster');
//$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('MWWMaster');
//$viewRenderer->setView($view);
// CLEANUP - remove items from global scope
// This will clear all our local boostrap variables from the global scope of 
// this script (and any scripts that called bootstrap).  This will enforce 
// object retrieval through the Applications's Registry

unset($frontController, $view, $configuration, $dbAdapter, $registry);
```

It seems to be some kind of .htaccess redirection problem but what i don't understand is that redirection performs perfectly in my admin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your htaccess after "RewriteEngine on":

```
RewriteBase /clients/donqui/
```